# Handling Null in Alexa

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I submitted a skill for Alexa and I got the following error from the Amazon team:

```
Issue: [StateIntent] Intent, [State] slot

Steps To Reproduce:

User: "Alexa open states symbols"
Skill: "Welcome to state symbols. Give me the name of a state and I will give you symbols used by the state. You can also say random before the state to get a random symbol or ask for specific information for a symbol for a state. I have information about state dog, state flower, state motto, state song, state tree, state bird and state mineral"
User: "tell me about {}"
Skill: "There was a problem with the requested skill's response"
```

In other words I am not handling situations where the slot is null. I tried several different things to address null in my code but all of them came back with the same error how can I address this? This is a sample section of the code.

```
  function   handleStateResponse(intent, session, callback){
    var state = intent.slots.State.value.toLowerCase(  );
    if (!states[state]){
      var speechOutput= `I couldn't find that state would you like to ask about another state?`;
      var repromptText = `Please try again`;
      var header =`not found`;
    }else{
      var state_dog = states[state].state_dog;
      speechOutput = `${capitalizeFirst(state)}'s state dog is the ${state_dog}`;
      repromptText = `Would you like to learn about another state?`;
      header  =capitalizeFirst(state);
    }
    var shouldEndSession=false;
    callback(session.attributes, buildSpeechletResponse(header, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. If you are not already logging your incoming requests you should do so. It includes valuable information to the request(ie intents, slots, IDs...). [Here](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/request-types-reference.html) you can see the structure of the different request types.

Ok, back in your user scenario the user leaves the slot empty. In other words Alexa sends a **request** to your lambda function with an empty slot. which looks something like this.

```
{
  "type": "IntentRequest",
  "intent": {
    "name": "StateIntent",
    "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
    "slots": {
      "State": {
        "name": "State",
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When Alexa sends a request with an empty slot it does not include a **value** member in your 'State'-object.

So to test for this. You only have to put one if-clause.

```
if (intent.slots.State.value) {
// *Here you can check if the value is right or just continue with the state_dog part*
}
else {
// *Here you can prepare the callback params for 'empty slot'*
}
```

I hope this helps and good luck with your certification.